# Cabinet door opening on it's own, how do I adjust this type of hinge?

Tags: doors, cabinets, hinges

One of the cabinet doors in our kitchen is swinging open on it's own.  You shut it and it slowly creeps back open.  I've seen the hinges that allow you to adjust x/y axis angles but these only have one screw on the frame side.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, that type of hinge isn't adjustable.  Is there any sort of play around the screws if you loosen them?

Answer (score 1):

No answer, but some ideas. Make sure the hinge is properly installed. It sounds like it was installed in the wrong orientation or the wrong type of hinge. Some hinges are design to be installed on lift up type cabinet doors. The spring action helps make the door feel less heavy and not slam shut. If you have other ones that work properly, check it against the others.  The picture you have shows only one screw which leads me to believe that it was designed for another type of door. Overtime, I can see the door coming out of alignment by pivoting on that single screw.

If you are certain it is properly installed, then find the spring mechanism and try to play with it using needle nose pliers or a screw driver. If no luck, then try to disable or remove the spring.

Comment: It is the correct type of door.  It is a single demountable hinge.  I only know this because I recently purchased a house that has them and had to research what they were or if I could even replace them.

Answer (score 1):

That's a single demountable hinge.  I've got double demountables on my kitchen cabinets.

I recently removed and painted the doors and had to adjust them slightly when I put them back on.  In my case, it was simply a matter of adjusting how deeply the hinges were slid into the door and/or frame before tightening the screws since no screws actually screw into wood.  In your case, since only the frame side is adjustable, loosen the single screw and pull out or pull in slightly and retighten.