# How to adjust hinges on cabinet that's started opening on its own

Tags: cabinets, hinges

Different hinges than [Cabinet door opening on it's own, how do I adjust this type of hinge?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/68495/23746). We got this cabinet with the house and it's been self-closing for about ten years. Recently, it's starting subbing open on its own, I think after my wife had tried to force it more closed (some items in it were hanging out).

The cabinet door seems mostly level:
[image: Level show cabinet door is mostly level]

### Hinges from top to bottom

[image] [image] [image] [image]

I've tried loosening and tightening the upper and lower screws, as I've heard that's a factor, but none of my changes have made much of a difference.

How do I get this back to swinging closed on its own rather than being self-opening?

Comment: This video may help. https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=how+to+adjust+cabinet+hinges&cvid=da790d4814524506a43758a94dd4a21a&aqs=edge.0.0j69i57j0l6j69i60.13380j0j1&pglt=43&PC=U531&ru=%2fsearch%3fq%3dhow%2bto%2badjust%2bcabinet%2bhinges%26cvid%3dda790d4814524506a43758a94dd4a21a%26aqs%3dedge.0.0j69i57j0l6j69i60.13380j0j1%26pglt%3d43%26FORM%3dANNTA1%26PC%3dU531&view=detail&mmscn=vwrc&mid=F68D4C21828E6D24B1BFF68D4C21828E6D24B1BF&FORM=WRVORC

Comment: Cure the cause first: train your wife to not leave stuff overhanging… Otherwise this will be an adjustment you will have to do **so** frequently.